# Center text in image and change text colour on hover

Tags: html, css, text

I'm trying to center text within the image and have the text change colour on hover.
However the divider between the text keeps knocking out the grid and I cant get the a:hover function to work? Thanks for helping.

This is what I am trying to achieve,
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=az791h&s=8#.U4i1MfldUrU

http://jsfiddle.net/pR8C4/

```
enter code here

    <div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="gallery-image"> 
            <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/>
            <p class="gallery-desc">top title</p>
            <div class="line-separator-three"></div>
            <p class="gallery-desc-bottom">bottom title</p></a>         
            </div>
        </li>
            <li>
                <div class="gallery-image">                
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/>
                <p></p></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="gallery-image">                
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="gallery-image">                
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="gallery-image">                
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="gallery-image">                
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="gallery-image">                
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="gallery-image">                
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/></a>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="gallery-image">                
                <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-g-320-220-1.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
            </li>
         </ul>
        </div>


    enter code here

#gallery {
    width:100%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-top:45px;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
#gallery ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#gallery ul li {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 30%;
    margin:1.66%;
    float:left;
}
#gallery li a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;

}
#gallery ul p {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    padding-left:20%;
    top:33%;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-family:'avenir';
    text-align:center;
}
#gallery ul a {
    color:#fff;
}
.gallery li a:hover{
    color:#FF8000;

}
#gallery ul img {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
}
.line-separator-three{
    width:50%;
    margin-left:25%;
    height:1px;
    background:#F5F5F5;
    border-bottom:1px solid #F5F5F5;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
}
enter code here
```

Comment: Do you want each image to have its own set of text?

Comment: yeah, theres a different picture for each image. Is it possible?

Comment: You have a few options. Either make the image a background image in a div then have 2 divs inside holding the text. OR Do some funky CSS to move a div on top of another that contains the text. OR if you really want to get funky and have it bloated  you can edit the picture in php so the text displays inside the picture.

Comment: How would I go about doing a css overlay? Would you just duplicate the boxes and insert text?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PA7cK/ - Now i wouldn't do it that way unless you know for SURE that there will be no animation or moving of the elements otherwise your going to be in for a very bad time. I would do the first way i suggested if i were you.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas il try it that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `:hover` effect you just have to change the class-selector `.gallery li a:hover` into an id-selector `#gallery li a:hover`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that :)